# Manually add cookies to request in C# Web test

Tags: performance-testing

Hi in one of my response i am getting this xml

```
<root><err>0</err><errDesc></errDesc><state>3</state><p1>{C4739B96-E12A-429B-9A03-0B5B5F814D3C}</p1><p2>{1C33A258-D50E-4D44-8309-83665FC6073E}</p2><p5>1</p5><p6>QdjXQJy0SVnamdLJqMMHz/Cxtu8Dbw21q5caSX9uwoBlZDvBfHJx1R7QfknQ+f564YfmnEyRnJ1TJ5DF+ZOK2g==</p6><p7></p7><p8>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</p8><p9>0</p9><returnmessage></returnmessage></root>
```

I need to extract id between p6 tags and pass it as a cookie in subsequent request as CPSession.

How to achieve this in C# Web Performance Testing.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to write a web test request plugin and in its prerequest method i am trying to write a method to achieve this with following code

```
 CookieContainer gaCookies = new CookieContainer(); Uri target = new   Uri("http://susday4446.corp.ncr.com:8091/core/ui/uiBrowser.aspx");    

>             gaCookies.Add(new Cookie("CPSession", "QdjXQJy0SVnamdLJqMMHz/Cxtu8Dbw21q5caSX9uwoBlZDvBfHJx1R7QfknQ+f564YfmnEyRnJ1TJ5DF+ZOK2g==");
> { Domain = target.Host }
```

But this is not able to add cookie in this request.
Right now all i am trying to do is passing CPSession as a cookie its value i have hardcoded.

Comment: Were yu able to get it?